# Mi ciclo se pasa del rango mostrandome: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Tags: java, array

Tengo lo siguiente, un método que pretende almacenar la cantidad de piezas por semana (este se calcula sumando las ventas que tiene cada día la misma, con un contador), el problema es que me maraca un error que se paso del índice.

Téngase en cuenta las matrices:

```
String[][] matGalletas = new String[5][2];
String[][] matRefrescos = new String[5][2];
String[][] matPapas = new String[7][2];
```

Aquí mando los datos al método:

```
System.out.println("\n\nIntroducamos los datos");
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        v.leer_vec(matGalletas, N, i+1);
    }
    if(i == 1) {
        v.leer_vec(matRefrescos, N, i+1);
    }
    if(i == 2) {
        v.leer_vec(matPapas, N, i+1);
    }
}
```

Y acá es donde los lleno y hago cosas con los datos:

```
public void leer_vec (String vec[][], int N, int ban) throws IOException {
    
    if(ban == 0) {
        dato = "Sandwich";
    }else {
        if(ban == 1) {
            dato = "Galleta";
        }else {
            if(ban == 2) {
                dato = "refresco";
            }else {
                if(ban == 3) {
                    dato = "Papas";
                }
            }
        }

    }
    for (i = 0; i <= N-1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del "+dato+" #"+ (i+1)+ " :");
        vec[i][0] = objLect.leer();
        System.out.println("Introduca el numero de unidades vendidas por dia del "+ dato +" #"+(i+1)+ " :");

        for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduza el numero de unidades vendidas de el dia: "+diasSemana[i]);
                cout = cout + Integer.parseInt(objLect.leer());
        }
        //vec[i][1] = String.valueOf(cout); 
        String numero = String.valueOf(cout);
        System.out.println(numero);

        vec[i][1] = numero; //aqui esta el error!
    }
    
    for (int x = 0; x < N-1; x++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(vec[i][1]) < Integer.parseInt(vec[i+1][1])){
                String tmp = vec[i+1][1];
                String tmpa = vec[i+1][0];
                vec[i+1][1] = vec[i][1];
                vec[i+1][0] = vec[i][0];
                vec[i][1] = tmp;
                vec[i][0] = tmpa;
            }
        }
    }               
}
```

Me marca el error justamente en: `vec[i][0] = cout`.

Ya hice la corrida anterior, si suma los números, pero al "asignarlos", me marca el error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Realmente no entiendo porque sale ese error, si los ciclos anteriores están en orden y en rango.

Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Comment: "i" que valor agarra antes de mostrar error.

Comment: En la funcion leer_vec Tienes dos bucle for en donde hace uso de la misma variable. El primero lo inicia en 0 todo bien. Pero al llegar al segundo la variable se inclementará hasta 6 y cuando pasa por el primer array te dara un error por esto: vec[6][1]=numero; //Porque este espacio no existe en los dos primeros string y por lo tanto te da un error.

Comment: Recomiendo usar dos variables diferente en los dos bucle for;

Comment: ¿Cuánto vale la constante N?

Comment: N vale 5 en el primer caso, 5 en el segundo y 7 en el tercero

Comment: Okey, gracias a todos!! efectivamente me agarra un valor de "i" muy distinto a los demas, gracias a todos: Daniel Briceño y pablo Lozano